# Securing asp.net web app with Form Authentication

Tags: asp.net, security

In ASP.NET web app, I have login.aspx.
I force that every user access through Login.aspx, setting that on web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="coockie_aut" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

My question is: 
Using form authentication and loginurl, would it prevent from trying to hack any web page without accessing first Login.aspx? Does it mean that allways *allways* there will be forced to access Login.aspx first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends what you mean by "hack".  Default Forms Authentication will redirect any request with *no session authentication token* to the login page.  There are all kinds of session stealing, man-in-the-middle, brute-force, and other varieties of attacks that you may still be vulnerable to.